# how to cast query.list() result objects to another object?

Tags: hibernate, casting, resultset

```
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   sb.append(" select * from Order where id in(:ids)");

   Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sb.toString());
   query.setParameterList("ids",ids);

   List<Order> results = (List<Order>)query.list();
```

getting
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.test.entity.Order

even i have tried as below , but no improvement, same error.

```
 List<?> list = query.list();
final List<Order> results = new ArrayList<Order>(list.size());
for(final Object obj : list) {
    results.add((Order)obj);
}
```

At last finally I have tried with .addEntity(Order.class). then it is working. but due to huge amount of results and data it is taking long time. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: If you have already tried addEntity(class) then it is the solution for your problem.. You may have to try pagination of the data. setMaxResults(500) something like that.

Comment: Is there any other way to typecast those result objects to entity objects.? because just for 700 records hibernate is taking too long  when i use .addEntity(class). And as per application for that scenario pagination may not be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns array of fields for Order so you cannot cast it to Order directly. Possible solutions:

1. Working with array (for example, if you need just several field)
2. Add addEntity(class) as was pointed @Zeus or rewrite query as 'from Order...'

Comment: I need all the fields of order entity. And As I mentioned .addEntity(class) is taking too long time(because having many columns), to fetch all orders, I am looking for another option.